# Wordpress Permalinks of Custom Post Type with Category Term

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i am trying to achieve custom structure of my permalinks but its not workin.
i have custom post type name tipps with default category taxonomy,
currently my strcutre is showing like /tipps/post-name/ which is assigned a category name suppose english. i want to get a url strcuture like

```
/english/post-name.
```

Simple i want to replace category term name with post type name. please let me know how i can do this. rewrite argument in register_post_type didn't worked for me, my current permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/`

i want to achieve url structure same like posts, my register_post_type capability type is also post.

Thanks

Comment: When you change the `rewrite` argument in `register_post_type()` you need to re-save permalinks in the Admin. Did you do that?

Comment: Could you also have a look on the server side to see if mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: currently i am not setting rewrite arguments. yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: i have re-saved my permalinks too